# Producing a webpage using leaflet

Tags: leaflet, cartography

New to leaflet. Figured a method of adding popups to show features at several geographic locations on a map. Each popup gives information via embedded URL link for a feature at that location. Displays fine. Problem arises in that ALL popups display URL of the 1st popup added to map instead of displaying their own unique URL for their individual location.

Question: Can it be rectified so that each popup displays its own assigned URL instead of adopting the URL of the first popup added to the map?

My code is as follows:

```
var myDataPoint = L.marker([51.491027, -0.224525]).addTo(map);

var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
popup
  .setLatLng(e.latlng)
  .setContent(e.latlng.toString() + '<a href=" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Theatre_Oxford"" +nr+"\""+" target=\"_blank\"> Information about theatre</a>"')
  .openOn(map);
}
map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a data structure that contains all of your points, with their location, link, name, etc. 
Then you can loop through the data, creating a specific marker for each one.

Here is an example JSBin: http://jsbin.com/rurane/2/edit?html,js,output

And here is the key part of code from it:

```
var data = [
{
  "name": "Questors Theatre", 
 "coordinates": [51.5116172, -0.3095337], 
  "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Questors_Theatre"
}, 
{
  "name": "Charles Cryer Studio Theatre", 
   "coordinates": [51.3659217, -0.159608], 
  "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Cryer_Theatre"
}, 
{"name": "Savoy Theatre", 
  "coordinates": [51.510139,-0.121], 
 "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savoy_Theatre"

} 

];

for (i in data){

    var marker = L.marker(data[i].coordinates).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup(data[i].name+": <a href='"+data[i].url+"'target='_blank'>Wikipedia link</a>");
}
```

Comment: C.M.R Rose I've tested your code and it's precisely what's required. I wish to extend my appreciation for enlightening me about a solution to an issue that's baffled me for several days.

Comment: Thanks @user94607! Would you please mark this answer as 'correct' then? It helps me reach the reputation points that I need for permissions on this site